# fullscreen website shows horizontal scrollbar and is cut on the right

Tags: css, fullscreen

I'm working on this website and I can't figure out how to fix the problem.
if you use a fullscreen browser window you will see it perfectly (any major browser) but if the window is smaller, it shows the horizontal scrollbar plus cuts the website on the right of around 50px.
I can't change the design to make it more easy to do.

here's the link, you can see both html and css

http://www.ircm.comunicazioneimmagine.eu/

Comment: link gives HTTP 401

Answer (score 1):

Using fixed size layout will cause problems with different screen resolutions. You should use fluid layouts to resolve the problem.

- [Fluid Layout Guide](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/)
- [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

If you don't want to use fluid layouts.

Put all the content into a div with `margin: 0 auto` and add `text-align: center` to the body (IE explorer compatible). Choose a background that looks nice with the page and you're done.

But if the screen resolution is less than actual page size there won't be any solution but resizing the page manually.

Comment: hi, i thought about using a fluid layout but since the website was designed by a graphic designer and i'm only supposed to code the html+css, i think i cant't use a fluid layout, the layout should be fixed to always be the same as the graphic designer intended

Answer (score 0):

the horizontal scroll bar is there cause your page exceeds the innerheight of the browser... my current res is 1920x1080 and I cannot see the bottom of the page. Perhaps try reducing the size of the big IRCM at the bottom.

Comment: hi, thnaks for the answer. i can't reduce the size of that IRCM, the website was designed by a graphic designer and should remain as it is

Comment: without changing any elements, I do not think you are going to achieve the result you want of the scroll bar not being there... the page is too tall, even for my screen resolution

Comment: mabe because i'm not english i don't really understand your message...how is it possibile that the height of the page affects the horizontal scrollbar? i'm talking about the scrollbar on the bottom of the page, not the one on the right

Comment: my humblest apologies... I was indeed referring to the vertical and not the horizontal scroll bar. I went back and took a futher look and my horizontal scroll bar only starts to show when I reduce the browser window much smaller. What screen resolution are you aiming to have as a minimum (with no horizontal scroll bar showing) and then let's work from there.

Comment: hi, don't worry for the misunderstanding! so, the agency told me that they want the website to be ok for resolutions < 1024